# Deploy ASP.NET Application to AWS

Tags: asp.net, amazon-web-services, deployment

I have problem while I deploy application to AWS. I have never done this part of job before, and when I deploy from Visual Studio I get error message

```
2018-07-03 12:23:53,788 [1] INFO  Amazon.AWSToolkit.S3FileFetcher - Loading hosted file 'flags/us.png' from local path 'C:\Users\denni\AppData\Local/AWSToolkit/downloadedfiles/flags/us.png'
2018-07-03 12:27:27,008 [53] INFO  Amazon.AWSToolkit.MobileAnalytics.AMAServiceCallHandler - Reponse from AMAClient.PutEvents(request) meta data: Amazon.Runtime.ResponseMetadata, response HttpStatusCode: Amazon.Runtime.ResponseMetadata
2018-07-03 12:35:27,857 [1] INFO  Amazon.AWSToolkit.VisualStudio.Shared.VSWebProjectInfo - EnvDTEProject.FullName lookup yielded 'C:\Users\denni\Desktop\JerrichoTerrace\JerichoTerrace\JerichoTerrace\JerichoTerrace.csproj'
2018-07-03 12:35:27,905 [1] INFO  Amazon.AWSToolkit.S3FileFetcher - Null/empty hosted files location override
2018-07-03 12:35:27,905 [1] INFO  Amazon.AWSToolkit.S3FileFetcher - Loading hosted file 'CloudFormationTemplates/TemplatesManifest.xml' from local path 'C:\Users\denni\AppData\Local/AWSToolkit/downloadedfiles/CloudFormationTemplates/TemplatesManifest.xml'
2018-07-03 12:35:28,038 [1] INFO  Amazon.AWSToolkit.MobileAnalytics.SimpleMobileAnalytics - Queuing analytics event in local queue with timestamp: 07/03/2018 10:35:28
2018-07-03 12:35:28,038 [1] INFO  Amazon.AWSToolkit.MobileAnalytics.SimpleMobileAnalytics - Queuing analytics event in local queue with timestamp: 07/03/2018 10:35:28
2018-07-03 12:35:28,102 [1] INFO  Amazon.AWSToolkit.S3FileFetcher - Null/empty hosted files location override
2018-07-03 12:35:28,102 [1] INFO  Amazon.AWSToolkit.S3FileFetcher - Loading hosted file 'flags/us.png' from local path 'C:\Users\denni\AppData\Local/AWSToolkit/downloadedfiles/flags/us.png'
2018-07-03 12:35:28,150 [1] INFO  Amazon.AWSToolkit.S3FileFetcher - Null/empty hosted files location override
2018-07-03 12:35:28,150 [1] INFO  Amazon.AWSToolkit.S3FileFetcher - Loading hosted file 'AccountTypes.xml' from local path 'C:\Users\denni\AppData\Local/AWSToolkit/downloadedfiles/AccountTypes.xml'
2018-07-03 12:35:28,166 [1] INFO  Amazon.AWSToolkit.S3FileFetcher - Null/empty hosted files location override
2018-07-03 12:35:28,166 [1] INFO  Amazon.AWSToolkit.S3FileFetcher - Loading hosted file 'AccountTypes.xml' from local path 'C:\Users\denni\AppData\Local/AWSToolkit/downloadedfiles/AccountTypes.xml'
2018-07-03 12:35:36,491 [1] INFO  Amazon.AWSToolkit.MobileAnalytics.SimpleMobileAnalytics - Queuing analytics event in local queue with timestamp: 07/03/2018 10:35:36
2018-07-03 12:35:40,945 [1] INFO  Amazon.AWSToolkit.MobileAnalytics.SimpleMobileAnalytics - Queuing analytics event in local queue with timestamp: 07/03/2018 10:35:40
2018-07-03 12:35:42,709 [37] INFO  Amazon.AWSToolkit.VisualStudio.AWSToolkitPackage - Publishing 'JerichoTerrace' to Amazon Web Services
2018-07-03 12:35:42,741 [57] INFO  Amazon.AWSToolkit.VisualStudio.AWSToolkitPackage - ..building configuration 'Debug|Any CPU' for project 'JerichoTerrace'
2018-07-03 12:35:52,725 [1] INFO  Amazon.AWSToolkit.VisualStudio.BuildProcessors.WebAppProjectBuildProcessor - IVsUpdateSolutionEvents.UpdateSolution_Done, fSucceeded=1, fModified=1, fCancelCommand=0
2018-07-03 12:35:53,029 [57] INFO  Amazon.AWSToolkit.VisualStudio.BuildProcessors.WebAppProjectBuildProcessor - Project build completed successfully, starting package build
2018-07-03 12:35:53,036 [57] INFO  Amazon.AWSToolkit.VisualStudio.AWSToolkitPackage - ..creating deployment package obj\Debug\Package\JerichoTerrace.zip...
2018-07-03 12:35:53,077 [50] INFO  Amazon.AWSToolkit.VisualStudio.AWSToolkitPackage - ....packaging -  executing target(s) "Build;Package"
2018-07-03 12:36:02,400 [21] INFO  Amazon.AWSToolkit.VisualStudio.AWSToolkitPackage - ....packaging -  Csc: build warning: 'Controllers\EstimatesViewModelsController.cs' at (581,41): This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously. Consider using the 'await' operator to await non-blocking API calls, or 'await Task.Run(...)' to do CPU-bound work on a background thread.
2018-07-03 12:36:15,260 [8] INFO  Amazon.AWSToolkit.VisualStudio.AWSToolkitPackage - ....packaging -  CreateProviderList: build error: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Web\Deploy\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.MSDeploy.Common.targets' at (55,5): Web deployment task failed. (Cannot connect to the database 'MojaBaza'.  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_CANNOT_CONNECT_TO_DATABASE.)

Cannot connect to the database 'MojaBaza'.  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_CANNOT_CONNECT_TO_DATABASE.
Object of type 'dbFullSql' and path 'data source=DESKTOP-0L8HK6U\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=MojaBaza;integrated security=True;user id=awsuser;pooling=False' cannot be created.
Failed to connect to server DESKTOP-0L8HK6U\SQLEXPRESS.
Cannot open database "MojaBaza" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'DESKTOP-0L8HK6U\denni'.
  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_EXECUTING_METHOD.
Failed to connect to server DESKTOP-0L8HK6U\SQLEXPRESS.
Cannot open database "MojaBaza" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'DESKTOP-0L8HK6U\denni'.
2018-07-03 12:36:15,260 [8] INFO  Amazon.AWSToolkit.VisualStudio.AWSToolkitPackage - ....packaging -  project build completed with errors.
2018-07-03 12:36:15,260 [57] ERROR Amazon.AWSToolkit.VisualStudio.BuildProcessors.WebAppProjectBuildProcessor - Deployment package build failed to complete.
2018-07-03 12:36:15,260 [57] INFO  Amazon.AWSToolkit.MobileAnalytics.SimpleMobileAnalytics - Queuing analytics event in local queue with timestamp: 07/03/2018 10:36:15
2018-07-03 12:36:15,260 [37] INFO  Amazon.AWSToolkit.VisualStudio.AWSToolkitPackage - ..build of project archive failed, abandoning deployment
2018-07-03 12:37:28,061 [77] INFO  Amazon.AWSToolkit.MobileAnalytics.AMAServiceCallHandler - Reponse from AMAClient.PutEvents(request) meta data: Amazon.Runtime.ResponseMetadata, response HttpStatusCode: Amazon.Runtime.ResponseMetadata
```

When I go to console.aws I found one field **Upload and Deploy**
So, will this field work If I deploy application in this step, will database will be deploy correctly. Guys, please help me

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the database connection string.
You must use database connection string with userid and password. Remove integrated security=True;
And then you need to also check your database's user permission for your application.

Comment: Yes, i change connection string everything looks good, but still get error
Cannot open database "MojaBaza" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'DESKTOP-0L8HK6U\denni'.

Comment: at database > Security : at User right click and create new user
at username and login name add your "DESKTOP-0L8HK6U\denni"
and then at Owned Schemas and Membership check some permission.